# Google EMM - The caller is not registered as an MDM issue

Tags: android, mdm, google-play-developer-api, android-for-work

I created MSA account and Oauth2 client ID and client secret. By using that client ID I am trying to use [generateSignupUrl](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/androidenterprise/v1/androidenterprise.enterprises.generateSignupUrl) API
. But this API is giving me following error.

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "androidenterprise",
    "reason": "forbiddenNotAnMdm",
    "message": "The caller is not registered as an MDM."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "The caller is not registered as an MDM."
 }
}
```

**Note:** I created Oauth2 credentials for the same account that is registered as MSA and also using the same account to use mentioned API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the Google Play EMM API you need to [register in the EMM Community](https://developers.google.com/android/work/register), you currently see this error because you are not registered. Note that to use the Google Play EMM API you will also need to implement a custom DPC app.

It you want to manage Android devices without registering in the EMM Community and without implementing a custom DPC app, you can use the new [Android Management API](https://developers.google.com/android/management/).

Comment: I already registered in EMM Community with the same account and I am using that accounts Outh2 client ID only.

Comment: JayTrivedi what @Fred means is not you as a person, but your company with a corporate domain should be authorised by Google as the EMM vendor. Only a Google employee internally can authorise your MSA to use these APIs. Note that if you ever accidentally delete the account, or if you created the service account in a personal project, this will be tied to the vendor (company) forever.